# How tolerant is XmlSerializer of change

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, xml-serialization, monogame

I am developing a mobile cross platform game (iOS, Android, WP8) using MonoGame & Xamarin. I have a class called PlayerData that holds data such as high score and other stats. I write and read it using XmlSerializer. After releasing the game, assume I change the base class of PlayerData, add new fields, and remove some existing ones then I release it again as an update. Will XmlSerializer be able to successfully read the the saved XML data of the previous version which doesn't map exactly to the updated PlayerData class? under which conditions would it fail? Do you advise any better alternative for future projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` itself cares very little about change. If it can't serialize a property into the class, the data is ignored. It is up to you how to handle migrations from `PlayerData` version 1.0 to 2.0.

I would recommend associating a version number to your `PlayerData` class. Now you can track which version of `PlayerData` your application is trying to load. If it's version 1.0, and you're now on 2.0, then you have to write logic to migrate any properties containing data you wish to keep. How you do the actual migration is up to you.

For example, after releasing an updated `PlayerData` class, a simple way to implement this migration is to create another class called `PlayerDataV1`. `PlayerDataV1` can be setup the same way as `PlayerData`, or even inherit `PlayerData`. Now during profile loads, you can deserialize version 1.0 profiles into this class, and migrate them into the new class structure using migration methods you create in `PlayerDataV1`.